# Store previous template parameter

Tags: c++

Lets say I have a method:

```
template<typename T>
void methodA(T val) {

}
```

I make 2 separate calls with different parameters to this function. Is there a way to store each of the types T has been?

Comment: For what purpose ?

Comment: And store in what form?

Comment: `methodA<A>` and `methodA<B>` are completely unrelated funtions. "calls with different parameters to this function"...this is not a funciton, it is a template from which you can instantiate functions.  Where do you want to store `T` ? and why?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your question you are intreseted in finding the type of the `T` . we can find it by this way

```cpp
#include <typeinfo>

template<typename T>
void methodA(T val) {
   std::cout<<"val is of type: "<<typeid(val).name()<<std::endl;
}
```

we can deduce any type name by using this function available in `typeinfo`